# C# - Посылка GET или POST запроса в UWP приложениях

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, uwp

Всем привет! Возник такой вопрос. Как сделать GET или POST запрос на сервер с uwp программы написанной на C#? И получить ответ? Ответ получаю в JSON.

Comment: А как вы пробовали?

Comment: посмотрите вот тут есть примеры обобщённых GET, POST, PUT и DELETE запросов: https://github.com/MrModest/ShikiApiLib/blob/master/ShikiApiLib/ApiQuery.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Я её использовал для написания переносимой библиотеки, которая в том числе должна поддерживать UWP, так что, скорее всего, подойдёт и вам.

Также для парсинга JSON-ответов советую [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) 
Устанавливается легко через поиск NuGet пакетов или команду: 
`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

Также можете посмотреть примеры написания в [этом репозитории](https://github.com/MrModest/ShikiApiLib/blob/master/ShikiApiLib/ApiQuery.cs). 
В частности, для работы с запросами тут подключены:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
```